# Render .ics file attachment within Outlook (like Gmail)

Tags: php, laravel, email, outlook, icalendar

I'm sending an email when a user books an event - the email contains a .ics file attachment containing the event information.

When sent to a Gmail account, it renders the event detail within the email body (like the image below), automatically adding the event to their calendar:

[image: Gmail event rendering within email body]

...but I'm struggling to get the same behaviour when sending the email (with attachment) to an Outlook email account.

Longshot - but has anyone dealt with this, or would be able to point me in a  direction?

**Can provide the .ics file if required.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get ics calendar invitation to automatically add to calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354486/how-to-get-ics-calendar-invitation-to-automatically-add-to-calendar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually corresponds to a MIME structure issue, especially if you got it working with some clients. See [Multipart email with text and calendar: Outlook doesn't recognize ics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523861/multipart-email-with-text-and-calendar-outlook-doesnt-recognize-ics/19535685#19535685)

Comment: Got it working - marked your answer as correct as it helped get me to where I needed to be! :)