# How to attach an ICS (calendar invite) to an email and have it automatically accepted and added to calendar?

Tags: email, gmail, email-attachments, icalendar

It seems when you get an email from a confirmation of a flight booking or an Airbnb reservation, GMail automatically adds an event to your calendar that is already pre-approved. Wondering how that happens? I've looked at all the other answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354486/how-to-get-ics-calendar-invitation-to-automatically-add-to-calendar) and was able to get the Calendar invite to show up on the email and Google Calendar but not to have it be automatically approved. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/flandrade/394d9df95e1be2a584f267ae91505239) was also useful in getting to this point, but now I can't find any information. Even more confusing: if you look at the Flights/Airbnb reservation emails, you won't see any attachments to the emails (no `.ics`). This is what my event data for the ics library looks like:

```js
const event = {
    start: startDate,
    end: endDate,
    status: 'CONFIRMED',
    busyStatus: 'FREE',
    organizer: {
      name: myName,
      email: myEmail,
    },
    attendees: [
      {
        name,
        email,
        rsvp: true,
        partstat: 'ACCEPTED',
      },
    ],
    url: calUrl,
    title: calTitle,
    summary: calSummary,
    description: calDescription,
    location: address,
    productId: productId,
    method: 'PUBLISH',
  };
```