# .ics file events not being added to calendar automatically

Tags: email, email-attachments, icalendar, email-headers

I'm trying and failing to get `.ics` files (that have been sent as an email attachments) to be automatically added to the user's calendar.  This [Apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253610368) suggests this has been stopped, but I'm almost certain that I've been sent `.ics` files since then that have been automatically added to my calendar.

I don't think the problem is with the `.ics` files; I took the `.ics` file that I was emailed and which I'm sure was automatically added to my calendar, and tried sending it to myself, but to no avail (I can click on it and it then gets added an works perfectly).  I presume there's a problem with the email headers, which may be mismatching sources/authentication.  I tried this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354486/how-to-get-ics-calendar-invitation-to-automatically-add-to-calendar) but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have an email (sent by somebody else) where this works? Look at the email's source and compare it to your email's source. Maybe you pass the wrong mime type. If you need more help, provide a [mcve].